# why my curl command getting bad request on plurasight api

Tags: curl

curl "https://app.pluralsight.com/player/api/graphql" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Referer: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models&author=janani-ravi&name=28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9&clip=3&mode=live" -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H "Origin: https://app.pluralsight.com" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cookie: AMCV_70D658CC558978FF7F000101"%"40AdobeOrg=1099438348"%"7CMCIDTS"%"7C17982"%"7CvVersion"%"7C2.1.0"%"7CMCMID"%"7C30770380242554347904237237541268829105"%"7CMCAAMLH-1554174897"%"7C3"%"7CMCAAMB-1554217056"%"7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y"%"7CMCOPTOUT-1553619456s"%"7CNONE"%"7CMCAID"%"7CNONE"%"7CMCSYNCSOP"%"7C411-17989; profileScores=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0; _psga=GA1.2.1800336076.1553570093; _psga_gid=GA1.2.7441612.1553570093; __cfduid=d2d2393bc58e937f38c2d3a4b521460c51553570085; dyn_previousPage=https://app.pluralsight.com/player; ajs_user_id="%"221f50ad3b-145b-431c-a537-f4906ad82f00"%"22; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_anonymous_id="%"22246a8a14-e11b-4755-98e7-e34d40ae4dc4"%"22; NPS_a97f541b_last_seen=1553570311749; PsJwt-production=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJoYW5kbGUiOiIxZjUwYWQzYi0xNDViLTQzMWMtYTUzNy1mNDkwNmFkODJmMDAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTM1NzAzMTgsImV4cCI6MTU1NDE3NTExOH0.MvdGJoi-ZN5n6uqxlF36Y1_pPsD3pr59izn9nB9Fn-c; www-status-production=1; _sdsat_v03 - Global - User ID=1f50ad3b-145b-431c-a537-f4906ad82f00; __cfruid=7c007c6a33fb1e75dde57993c487c7625d222857-1553612244; __cf_bm=0388378ed8a25d31b61e6863c033c9702f7caac9-1553613222-1800-AVhbUzCcvCP2y0RpvU/66f2+Q1Y9O4HL/ldWr6eTp+Qxaubi80jB4ssIxZcqZfyJ5mZQuth6WTnZbbViThYiru8=; AMCVS_70D658CC558978FF7F000101"%"40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true" -H "TE: Trailers" --data "{""query"":""\n        query viewClip {\n          viewClip(input: {\n            author: \""janani-ravi\"", \n            clipIndex: 3, \n            courseName: \""python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models\"", \n            includeCaptions: false, \n            locale: \""en\"", \n            mediaType: \""mp4\"", \n            moduleName: \""28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9\"", \n            quality: \""1280x720\""\n          }) {\n            urls {\n              url\n              cdn\n              rank\n              source\n            },\n            status\n          }\n        }\n      "",""variables"":{}}"

Answer (score 0):

Because you query is little bit wrong, check quotes escaping and query structure

compare your query:

```
{""query"":""\n query viewClip {\n viewClip(input: {\n author: \""janani-ravi\"", \n clipIndex: 3, \n courseName: \""python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models\"", \n includeCaptions: false, \n locale: \""en\"", \n mediaType: \""mp4\"", \n moduleName: \""28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9\"", \n quality: \""1280x720\""\n }) {\n urls {\n url\n cdn\n rank\n source\n },\n status\n }\n }\n "",""variables"":{}}
```

with working one:

```
{"query": "{\n  viewClip(input: {author: \"janani-ravi\", clipIndex: 3, courseName: \"python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models\", includeCaptions: false, locale: \"en\", mediaType: \"mp4\", moduleName: \"28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9\", quality: \"1280x720\"}) {\n    urls {\n      url\n      cdn\n      rank\n      source\n    }\n    status\n  }\n}\n"}
```

prettified:

```
{
  viewClip(input: {
    author: "janani-ravi",
    clipIndex: 3,
    courseName: "python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models",
    includeCaptions: false,
    locale: "en",
    mediaType: "mp4",
    moduleName: "28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9",
    quality: "1280x720"
  }) {
    urls {
      url
      cdn
      rank
      source
    }
    status
  }
}
```

so working request will be:

```
curl  "https://app.pluralsight.com/player/api/graphql" \
  --compressed \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0" \
  -H "Accept: /" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" \
  -H "Referer: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models&author=janani-ravi&name=28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9&clip=3&mode=live" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
  -H "Origin: https://app.pluralsight.com" \
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
  -H "Cookie: AMCV_70D658CC558978FF7F000101"%"40AdobeOrg=1099438348"%"7CMCIDTS"%"7C17982"%"7CvVersion"%"7C2.1.0"%"7CMCMID"%"7C30770380242554347904237237541268829105"%"7CMCAAMLH-1554174897"%"7C3"%"7CMCAAMB-1554217056"%"7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y"%"7CMCOPTOUT-1553619456s"%"7CNONE"%"7CMCAID"%"7CNONE"%"7CMCSYNCSOP"%"7C411-17989; profileScores=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0; _psga=GA1.2.1800336076.1553570093; _psga_gid=GA1.2.7441612.1553570093; __cfduid=d2d2393bc58e937f38c2d3a4b521460c51553570085; dyn_previousPage=https://app.pluralsight.com/player; ajs_user_id="%"221f50ad3b-145b-431c-a537-f4906ad82f00"%"22; ajs_group_id=null; ajs_anonymous_id="%"22246a8a14-e11b-4755-98e7-e34d40ae4dc4"%"22; NPS_a97f541b_last_seen=1553570311749; PsJwt-production=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJoYW5kbGUiOiIxZjUwYWQzYi0xNDViLTQzMWMtYTUzNy1mNDkwNmFkODJmMDAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTM1NzAzMTgsImV4cCI6MTU1NDE3NTExOH0.MvdGJoi-ZN5n6uqxlF36Y1_pPsD3pr59izn9nB9Fn-c; www-status-production=1; _sdsat_v03 - Global - User ID=1f50ad3b-145b-431c-a537-f4906ad82f00; __cfruid=7c007c6a33fb1e75dde57993c487c7625d222857-1553612244; __cf_bm=0388378ed8a25d31b61e6863c033c9702f7caac9-1553613222-1800-AVhbUzCcvCP2y0RpvU/66f2+Q1Y9O4HL/ldWr6eTp+Qxaubi80jB4ssIxZcqZfyJ5mZQuth6WTnZbbViThYiru8=; AMCVS_70D658CC558978FF7F000101"%"40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true" \
  -H "TE: Trailers" \
  --data '{"query": "{\n  viewClip(input: {author: \"janani-ravi\", clipIndex: 3, courseName: \"python-scikit-learn-building-machine-learning-models\", includeCaptions: false, locale: \"en\", mediaType: \"mp4\", moduleName: \"28c11cee-cfc2-4fc5-b837-bbad57c682c9\", quality: \"1280x720\"}) {\n    urls {\n      url\n      cdn\n      rank\n      source\n    }\n    status\n  }\n}\n"}'
```